# Repair HTML Tag Brackets using Python

Tags: python, string

I have a lot of HTML text, like

```
text = 'Hello, how <sub> are </sub> you ? There is a <sub> small error </sub  in this text here and another one <sub> here /sub> .'
```

Sometimes HTML tags, such as `<sub>`,`</sub>` are missing their `<` brackets. This can lead to difficulties later in the code. Now, my question is: **How can I detect those missing brackets intelligently and repair them?**

The correct text would be:

```
text = 'Hello, how <sub> are </sub> you ? There is a <sub> small error </sub>  in this text here and another one <sub> here </sub> .'
```

Of course, I could hardcode all possible bracket configurations, but that would take too long as there are more errors like that in my text.

```
text = re.sub( r'</sub ', r'</sub>', text) 
text = re.sub( r' /sub>', r'</sub>', text)
```

...and the previous code might add another bracket to correct samples.

Comment: How do you know a given missing "bracket" wasn't intentionally omitted?

Comment: I do not believe that the code you have would add another bracket to correct samples because you have a space included.

Comment: The point of the question is the fact that the tag name "sub" could be any word, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! Here's a solution that does not hardcode the word `sub` and works on arbitrary tags, as long as there is only one bracket missing and the HTML tag contains no attributes (otherwise, how'd we know when the tag should be closed? We could use the `attr=""` format, but it gets dicey). Additionally, the tags need not be space-delimited as your example shows, which is not the usual case in HTML.

---

#### Code

```
import re

def repair(text, backwards=False):
    left_bracket, right_bracket = "<", ">"

    if backwards:
        left_bracket, right_bracket = ">", "<"

    i = 0

    while i < len(text):
        if text[i] == left_bracket:
            j = i + 1

            while j < len(text) and re.match(r"[/\w]", text[j]):
                j += 1

                if backwards and text[j-1] == "/":
                    break

            if j >= len(text) or text[j] != right_bracket:
                text = text[:j] + right_bracket + text[j:]

            i = j

        i += 1

    return text

def repair_tags(html):
    return repair(repair(html[::-1], True)[::-1])
```

---

#### Test

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    original = '''<li>
    <a>
        About Us
        <span>
            Learn more about Stack Overflow the company
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a>
        Business
        <span>
            Learn more about hiring developers or posting ads with us
        </span>
    </a>
</li>'''
    corrupted = '''li>
    <a
        About Us
        span>
            Learn more about Stack Overflow the company
        </span
    </a
/li>
<li
    <a
        Business
        span>
            Learn more about hiring developers or posting ads with us
        /span>
    </a
</li'''

    print(repair_tags(corrupted))
    print("repaired matches original?", repair_tags(corrupted) == original)
```

---

#### Output

```
<li>
    <a>
        About Us
        <span>
            Learn more about Stack Overflow the company
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a>
        Business
        <span>
            Learn more about hiring developers or posting ads with us
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
repaired matches original? True
```

---

#### How it works

Iterate through the string hunting for a bracket character. When one is found, step forward until the end of the string is hit or a non-word character is encountered. Place a companion bracket if the seek reaches the end of the string or the current non-word character is not the correct companion bracket.

Then, perform the same operation on the reversed string, switching the target brackets and making a slight adjustment to break on the `/` when seeking for the closing tag location.

Time complexity is not great due to the string building. Undoubtedly there's an easy regex, so take this as a proof of concept.

[Try it!](https://repl.it/@ggorlen/repairhtmltags)

Comment: This is a great answer ! Thank you so much for thinking about how to solve this in general !! This solved my problem.

Comment: Do you happen to have an idea for a better title for this question which would better describe the issue ?

Comment: Sure--no problem. This solution is probably overkill, but I think it's an interesting question that can be generalized a lot further. As for the title, I don't see any problem with it, but maybe "strings" -> "brackets" and "text" -> "HTML is a bit more specific, assuming I'm understanding the question correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I changed the title and the description accordingly.

Comment: `repair` is just a helper for `repair_tags()`, so call it with `repair_tags('If <i>W/i> this works?')`. The wrapper is necessary to perform the forward and backward traversals. Yeah, it's a bit ugly (hopefully I'll have a chance to clean it up in the future). Loving these HTML parsing questions!

Comment: Oh yes, that's right. Now it works! Very nice ! Thank you so much !! Your code is so helpful !

Comment: Almost everything is working now. However, I am facing one problem: Consider this string, which is completely fine: `s='<i>< , ></i>'`. If I run `repair_tags(s)`I get: `<i><> , <></i>`.  Maybe one should add to the code, that if there is a `" "` space after or before a `<` or a `>`, then it should not try to "repair" it... What do you think ?

Comment: Well, you can get arbitrarily complex depending on the rules you make up for the text input. The code I wrote makes the assumption that tags are defined as `<\w+>` only, so spaces are not permitted in HTML tags. In other words, tags with attributes like `<img src="cat.jpg">` are not supported by this repair function. That can be added, but then you're heading down a slippery slope with the bottom being writing an entire HTML parser library, so it's a good idea to enumerate all of the cases you want to handle up front, otherwise we're in feature creep/moving goalpost land.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. The problem is, that I am discovering as I go. I am transcribing the text, and sometimes, unexpected things like that happen. I have fixed the issue by simply adding `and text[j] != " "` to the `if j >= len(text) or text[j] != right_bracket`statement. I know, its really not beautiful to be in feature "creep/moving goalpost land", but for now, I see no other way. :)

Comment: Yeah, I understand the issue--in the absence of most of the constraints, I just made some up for the purposes of this answer, so it's mainly a proof of concept to help illustrate how you might go about setting up a solution that can be expanded upon as needed.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```py
text = 'Hello, how <sub> are </sub> you ? There is a <sub> small error </sub  in this text here and another one <sub> here /sub> .'

text_list = text.split();
for i, word in enumerate(text.split()):
    if 'sub' in word:
        if '<' != word[0]:
            word = '<' + word
        if '>' != word[-1]:
            word += '>'
        text_list[i] = word

result = ' '.join(text_list)
print(result)
```

output will be

```
Hello, how <sub> are </sub> you ? There is a <sub> small error </sub> in this text here and another one <sub> here </sub> .
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !

Answer (score 2):

I would search for an expression like `sub.*?/sub`. It does not assume anything about the brackets at all, but it will only match `sub` that is paired with `/sub`, decreasing the probability of false matches. The reluctant quantitifier `*?` is necessary to prevent it from matching the first `sub` and the last `/sub`:

Couple this with the fact that capture groups are allowed by [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
text = re.sub('<?sub>?(.*?)<?/sub>?', '<sub>\\1</sub>', text)
```

Answer (score 1):

using regex;

```
import re
text = 'Hello, how <sub are </sub> you ? There is a <sub> small error </sub  in this text here and another one <sub> here /sub> .'

text = re.sub(r'<?[^/]sub>?', '<sub>', text)
text = re.sub(r'<?/sub>?', '</sub>', text)

print(text)
```

output:

```
Hello, how <sub> are </sub> you ? There is a <sub> small error </sub>  in this text here and another one <sub> here </sub> .
```

**Edit**: how it works,

`re.sub(search pattern, replcement, string)` it will search for a string pattern 
and replace it with another

`'<?[^/]sub>?'` to explain this pattern meaning will take it apart:

`"<?"` means search for a text 'maybe' contains '<', '?' means existed or not

`[^/]` means it doesn't contain '/'

`'sub'` it must contain word 'sub'

`'>?'` it maybe contains '>'

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation !